# In wcf WebGet can not be reference

Tags: c#, wcf

Hi I am attempting to create a WCF service with Visual Studio 2010.

I have defined the following method:

```
    [OperationContract]
    int isUser(string name,string pass);
```

I then changed the operation to use WebGet with JSON serialization like below:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(
     UriTemplate = "ServiceInterface{name}",
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   int isUser(string name,string pass);
```

After the change, the class library builds, but it's not possible to reference it from another project.  The error message is:  Cannot find the namespace.

If I remove the WebGet attribute, then I am able to add a reference to this class library.  How can I use the WebGet attribute and still add a reference to this class library?

Thank you for your help

Comment: what message do you get?

Comment: cannot find the namespace MyClassLibrary's name

Comment: Can you post the complete class and the exact error as it appears when you try to build the project. Also can you tell me what version of .NET framework are you working with

Comment: @ Rajesh thank you ，my  version of NET framework is too low